# Web-service acess with R and SSOAP from cbr.ru

Tags: web-services, r, soap

I'm trying to retrieve data to R from CBR (Russia's Central Bank - cbr.ru) via their web-service platform. Basically, I was inspired by a code from [this example](http://arademaker.github.com/blog/2012/01/02/package-SSOAP.html) using SSOAP package for R.

```
wsdl <- 'http://www.cbr.ru/secinfo/secinfo.asmx?WSDL'
doc  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl)
def <- processWSDL(doc)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def) 
xmlstr.f <- ff@functions #gives the list of functions that can be accessed 
# just an example of retrieval attempt 
t1 <- new('dateTime',as.POSIXct('2012-10-10')) #creating an object of dateTime class as requested 
xmlstr.f$GCurve(t1) #trying to call SOAP server with GCurve function
```

and I receive the following error:

```
Error in .SOAP(server, .operation@name, parameters = as(parameters, "dateTime"),  : object '.operation' not found
```

Can anyone give me suggestions on what's going wrong here?

Comment: I get a different error, but I think there is a confusion between the R dateTime class and the service's expected dateTime class.